# What can cause an ORA-01722: invalid number error when the column is type NUMBER

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-view, ora-01722

Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production          0
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production                                                0
CORE    12.1.0.2.0      Production                                                            0
TNS for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production                                        0
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production                                                0

I have a complex view named tkd_gl1

```
SQL> desc tkd_gl1

Name                     Null?    Type
------------------------ -------- --------------
PRODUCT_FAMILY_ID        NOT NULL NUMBER
APPLICATION_ID           NOT NULL NUMBER
PROC_TYPE_ID             NOT NULL NUMBER
REG_PACKSET_ID           NOT NULL NUMBER
REGISTRATION_ID          NOT NULL NUMBER
PACKSET_SPECIFICATION_ID NOT NULL NUMBER
PRODUCT_ID               NOT NULL NUMBER
REG_PACK_COUNTRY_ID      NOT NULL NUMBER
REG_PACKSET_COUNTRY_ID   NOT NULL NUMBER
PRODUCT_DETAIL_SET_ID    NOT NULL NUMBER
SUBSTANCE_ID             NOT NULL NUMBER
LOCAL_APPROVED_CHANGE_ID          NUMBER
Regulatory Action Type            VARCHAR2(500)
Comments                          VARCHAR2(4000)
Reviewing Country Name   NOT NULL VARCHAR2(500)
Basis Label Country      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(500)
CPP Reference Country    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(500)



select count(*) from tkd_gl1;
select distinct product_family_id from tkd_gl1;
select product_family_id from tkd_gl1;
select min(product_family_id),max(product_family_id) from tkd_gl1;
select product_family_id from tkd_gl1;
```

--All of these return ORA-01722

Comment: Is the view itself perhaps selecting from fields which *aren't* numbers?  Or perhaps nullable numbers?

Comment: can we see the content of the view ?

Comment: need to see the view.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a [MRE] including the DDL statement used to create the view and the definitions of the tables used in the view.

Comment: As has been suggested, the problem is almost certainly in the view definition.  Most likely, the view is either trying to cast a non-numeric column to a number or is trying to join a numeric and a non-numeric column and the non-numeric column is being implicitly cast to a number and failing.